# How to reduce mdf and ldf size through statistics in sql server 2005/2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

i have an issue, that is i found my **mdf size:13 GB** and **ldf size:96 GB** ,i deleted all the records from the database tables to reduce size in mdf as well as ldf,i did **use DATA_AQUA
go
exec sp_updatestats
go also** even though the **DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS** command gives null values,
my expectation is i deleted all records but it should show the size less but it is still showing old size, how to resolve this please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Start reading the documentation.

NONE of your steps will make any of those files smaller per documentation.

- The LDF points to you not having made a backup and truncated the log, quite "ever". That is significantly bad and I dare saying the file size is not your problem but the fact that you have no backup and do not seem to care about your data.
- Once you have backups, you can reinitialize the LDF using a sequence of switching to simple recovery then running a shrink operation.
- Regarding the MDF - same thing. You have to reorganize the database using a maintenance task to shrink it.

Why do you think that deleting records, using updatestats will magically shrink the file?

Answer (score 0):

For the LDF you should either be doing regular [Transaction Log Backups](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190440%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), or switching from [Full Recovery Mode to Simple Recovery Mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189275.aspx).  It will grow until you take one of those two actions.  Note in either case, after performing the action you should [shrink the ldf](http://www.falconitservices.com/support/KB/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=89) file.

If you've deleted records from the main DB the mdf will not shrink automatically, but you can use the same shrink mechanism from the ldf (aka database->tasks->shrink->files or `DBCC Shrinkfile (<DBName>, <TargetSize>)`